# TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(thisType) to return properties, which are write-only

Tags: c#, propertydescriptor, typedescriptor

I'm trying to get all properties from a type, but using TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(thisType) will only supply me with properties, that has both setter and a getter. I have write-only properties. Are there a way to retrieve a PropertyDescriptorCollection including those?

/Asger

Comment: Re your comments; I'll post an update with a "trick" for the scenario where you don't know the types...

Comment: Actually, I just re-read your comments; is the write-only property on the interface? If so you can use the original code (see the edits) and just use the interface as the reflected type.

Comment: Yes the property is on the interface. I tried that with your original example (before the edits, if that's what you mean?), but I got an exception about not being able to bind the delegate - or something like that - I have to try again to get the actual exception message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write-only properties are a rare beast, and don't exist in the System.ComponentModel / PropertyDescriptor space. `PropertyDescriptor`s are designed to be readable. I could probably hack `HyperDescriptor` to shim write-only properties, but it would be a hack - and it would presumably have to throw exceptions for `get`, which could impact calling code quite a bit.

As an aside; I generally advise *against* write-only properties; the text-book example that people trot out is passwords (`public string Password {private get;set;}`) - I'd much rather have a `void SetPassword(string newPassword)` method...

What is it that you actually want to do? There are a range of options here, all very achievable:

- use reflection alone (slow; maybe not an option)
- use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` (very easy)
- use `Expression.Compile` (a *little* harder, but not much)
- use `Reflection.Emit` (quite hard)
- shim write-only properties into `PropertyDescriptor` (quite hard)

If you let me know what you actually want to do (rather than the way you are currently trying to do it), I might be able to help more.

As an example using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` (note you would want to stash the delegate somewhere and re-use it lots of times):

**edited to show how to do it if you don't know the specific types at runtime**

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Foo
{
    public string Bar { private get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Bar; // to prove working
    }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ISetter setter = Setter.Create(typeof(Foo), "Bar");
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        setter.SetValue(foo, "abc");
        string s = foo.ToString(); // prove working
    }
}
public interface ISetter {
    void SetValue(object target, object value);
}
public static class Setter
{
    public static ISetter Create(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        if (propertyName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");
        return Create(type.GetProperty(propertyName));
    }
    public static ISetter Create(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        if(property == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("property");
        if (!property.CanWrite) throw new InvalidOperationException("Property cannot be written");
        Type type = typeof(TypedSetter<,>).MakeGenericType(
                property.ReflectedType, property.PropertyType);
        return (ISetter) Activator.CreateInstance(
            type, property.GetSetMethod());
    }
}

public class TypedSetter<TTarget, TValue> : ISetter {
    private readonly Action<TTarget, TValue> setter;
    public TypedSetter(MethodInfo method) {
        setter = (Action<TTarget, TValue>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Action<TTarget, TValue>), method);
    }
    void ISetter.SetValue(object target, object value) {
        setter((TTarget)target, (TValue)value);
    }
    public void SetValue(TTarget target, TValue value) {
        setter(target, value);
    }
}
```

---

Or alternatively using the `Expression` API (.NET 3.5):

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

class Foo
{
    public string Bar { private get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Bar; // to prove working
    }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Action<object,object> setter = Setter.Create(typeof(Foo), "Bar");
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        setter(foo, "abc");
        string s = foo.ToString();
    }
}

public static class Setter
{
    public static Action<object,object> Create(Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        if (propertyName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");
        return Create(type.GetProperty(propertyName));
    }
    public static Action<object,object> Create(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        if(property == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("property");
        if (!property.CanWrite) throw new InvalidOperationException("Property cannot be written");

        var objParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "obj");
        var valueParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");
        var body = Expression.Call(
            Expression.Convert(objParam, property.ReflectedType),
            property.GetSetMethod(),
            Expression.Convert(valueParam, property.PropertyType));
        return Expression.Lambda<Action<object, object>>(
            body, objParam, valueParam).Compile();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you very much for your prompt reply! 

The setters works as a proxy to configure some view elements in a webforms application. A presenter will via a view interface set the required configuration on the view - it uses reflection over the interface and the view implementation to end up using SetValue to set the config on the view. As our systems grows, and there are a lot of views (nested inside each other), the reflection part is being really slow.

Comment: I think your delegate-solution seems like the right approach for me - I have the logic for the SetValue hidden away in a general class. I'll go try it out immediately. 

Are there any more documentation/"getting started writeups" about any of the other possibilities that you would recommend?

Comment: I've just looked a little closer at it. One problem with the delegate solution, is that I do not know the type of the view implementation (your Foo) at compile time, only the interface which Foo implements. At run time I have the type. Then I should use reflection to create the delegate - I don't know if that'll ruin performance then...

Comment: Wow. That's impressive answer. Thank you very much for that! I've just implemented your expression solution in part of the system, and even without caching of the delegate the profiled running time for the "SetValue" is cut in half.

Thank you very much!

PS. I do not yet have enough reps to up-vote your answer. I will do later!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`System.Type.GetProperties()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) instead, that returns all properties. Notice that this returns a `PropertyInfo[]` instead of a `PropertyDescriptorCollection`.

Comment: FYI: only the parameterless version returns all public properties. There's an overload that takes some BindingFlags you can use to get all the properties if you want them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I do need the PropertyDescriptor and not the PropertyInfo as I'm using Marc Gravell HyperTypeDescriptor because og perfomance issues. So using Type.GetProperties is unfortunately not a solution.

Comment: Wow... if just invoking a setter method was that fast :-) Thanks for the reply, I'll go read now, and will reply shortly!